# Firefox not showing full CSS animation, but Chrome and IE does

Tags: css, firefox, css-animations

I am working on an animation with these steps:

1. Flip card from front to back
2. Scale back
3. Display a message

The animation works okay in Chrome and IE, but for some reason step 1 in Firefox doesn't show the latter part of the flip animation.

When I'm pausing the animation in Firefox Animation tool, the back side is acutally showing as you can see in this image: [Open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iL40.png)

I have read multiple threads here and tried a bunch of things including adding -moz keyframes and transitions, but I am not able to get it to work.

I also have a smaller issue, which is that I want step 2 to stay inside the flip-container. However, if I add overflow: hidden to .flip-container I also lose the nice 3d-effect of the flip itself.

You find my code here: https://codepen.io/larsbing/pen/ExYbmPR

```
    .flip-container {
        position: relative;
        width: 275px;
        height: 367px;
        -webkit-perspective: 1000;
        -ms-perspective: 1000;
        perspective: 1000;
        -ms-transform: perspective(1000px);
        -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform: 1000;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .flipper {
        -webkit-transition: 2s;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -ms-transition: 2s;
        -moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
        -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: 2s;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        position: relative;
    }

    .front,
    .back {
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: 2s;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        -ms-transition: 2s;
        -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        transition: 2s;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
        position: absolute;
    }

    .front {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }

    .back {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

    .flip-container.click .back {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }

    .flip-container.click .front {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    }
    .zoom {
        width: 275px;
        height: 367px;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -webkit-animation: zoomin 1s ease-in;
        animation: zoomin ease-in 1s 1;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
        animation-delay: 2s;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    @keyframes zoomin {
        from {
            transform: scale(1);
        }
        to {
            transform: scale(3);
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes zoomin {
        from {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        }
        to {
            -webkit-transform: scale(3);
        }
    }

    .red {
        animation: 3.5s fadeIn;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        visibility: hidden;
        padding: 10px;
        z-index: 3;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        width: 100%;
        background: red;
    }

    @keyframes fadeIn {
        99% {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        100% {
            visibility: visible;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you allowed to change html/js ? For some reason zoomin animation breaks it. I created a fiddle to check fixed result 

https://jsfiddle.net/gob8zk6a/

Comment: Thanks alot for looking at this, I see that you managed to make the back side visible in FF by changing the query selector from zoom-page to flipper. Awesome! It is okay to change the JS, I've should've  mentioned that. Do you have any idea how I can accomplish overflow: hidden on the latter part of the animation so the scale part of the animation stays within the container?

Comment: You can add overflow: hidden to .flip-container